# Реализация многопоточности на php

Tags: php, асинхронность

Здравствуйте, есть задача реализовать перебор всех email из сайта и удалить несуществующие.

Есть такой код на php:

```
$str='test@gmail.com'; $alter=new CCheckMail(); print "E-mail: ".$str." - ".($alter->execute($str)?'существует':'не существует');
```

Class: https://pastebin.com/DnjGajXG

> Время выполнения скрипта
>
> 1 проверка ~ 0.3634250164032
>
> 10 проверок ~ 3.5882749855518
>
> 100 проверок ~ 38.591406017542

В Базе ~ 4000000 почт и для этого понадобиться в лучшем случае 17 суток, что очень много.

Как реализовать многопоточность или может быть есть какие-то другие способы ускорить перебор?

Comment: Да это еще нормально. Работа с реальной почтой - 50-80 сообщений в минуту. А у Вас около 150-ти проверок. Многопоточность - в помощь, но если нет ограничений на подключение к почте. Иначе многопотоки будут просто в очереди стоять))

Comment: Используйте многопоточность в новой версии PHP или многозадачность через менеджеры задач типа Gearman.

Comment: Как реализовать их, можно примеры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В PHP есть несколько встроенных возможностей по управлению процессами (`PCNTL` , `pthreads`). скрипт можно распаралелить к примеру так :

```
//функция для отправки процесса в отдельную нить
function initThreads(array $callbacks) {

        foreach ($callbacks as $call) {
            $pid = pcntl_fork();
            if ($pid == 0) {
                $call();
                exit;
            }
        }

}

$callbacks = [];

// соберем тестовый массив с замыканиями , каждый из которых будет 
// выполнен асинхронно от другого
foreach(range(0, 10) as $thread){
    $callbacks[] = function()use( $thread ){
        print_r([
            'this thread' => $thread ,
            'this out' => implode(',',range(0 , $thread+1))
        ]);
    };
}

initThreads($callbacks);
```

В данном примере все замыкания будут выполнены асинхронно , единственное надо учитывать кол-во порождаемых процессов и то что PCNTL будет работать только в CLI режиме.

---

Еще 1 способ заключается в асинхронном запуске через `xargs` , суть в том что бы передать в php параметр $argv , в твоем случае email адрес.

- Создаем файл с email адресами 'emails'
- запускаем `xargs`

`< emails xargs -P 20 -n 1 -I % sh -c 'php thrun.php %'`

тут мы считываем каждую строчку из файла и отправляем ее в наш обработчик.
пусть будет `thrun.php` и передаем ему параметр `%`

в самом `php` обращаемся к этому параметру через `$argv` массив. 
далее ты пишеш свой обработчик который что-то там делает. 
Все получили асинхронный запуск обработчика для всех твоих email.

Comment: Спасибо, второй способ понял. Первый для меня темный лес, как будто не php:)

Comment: Ну впервом тот же концепт , с помощью `pcntl_fork();` разветвить (fork) текущий запущенный процесс , А `calback` тут просто для примера , в родительском процессе набиваеш очередь, без выполнения и отправляеш ее обработчик , где каждая функция выполнится уже в отдельном процессе.

Comment: а как можно CLI режим включать, работаю через open server?

Comment: Не разу не пользовался , но думаю точно также , просто запуск php скрипта из командной строки

Comment: pcntl есть только в posix cli. Его нет в win.

Comment: ну по условию не было уточнения по этому поводу.

Answer (score 2):

Я так понимаю, основное время отнимает ожидание ответа от почтового сервера.
Вам нужна не многопоточность, а какая-никакая асинхронность, пул событий.

В простом php ничего подобного(без расширений) нет.
Вам может помочь:

- Сервер очередей.
  Что-нибудь вроде RabbitMQ. Заполняете его своими миллионами задач, потом запускаете несколько воркеров(отдельных скриптов), которые по одному берут из очереди emailы и проверяют их. Больше воркеров(их можно запускать на разных машинах) - быстрее работа.
- multicurl.
  Позволяет одновременно выполнять пачку http-запросов. Отправляете пачку запросов на скрипт обработчик, ждёте ответа от всей пачки.
- Запросы в php-cli без stdout.
  С помощью `exec('process_email.php email1@example.org 2>&1 >/dev/null')` запускаете пачку скриптов без ожидания ответа. Скрипты проверяют свой диапазон email и сами помещают результаты в хранилище.
  Тут есть сложность с обратной связью, так что придётся изначально всё рассчитать:
  Например, запускаете 50 таких скриптов, каждый обрабатывает все email с `id%50 == НомерСкрипта`.

*Возможно имеет смысл для подобной задачи взять другой инструмент(не php). Тот же nodejs, гораздо легче справится с подобной задачей.*

Comment: "Тот же nodejs, гораздо легче справится с подобной задачей" http://reactphp.org/ ?

Comment: Таки всякие phpDaemon - тоже "более подходящие" другие инструменты